# Use FileInputStream to load properties from both relative path and absolute path

Tags: java, java-io, properties-file

I have written a component which others use.
Component configures itself by reading properties files.
The path to properties files can be specified by the user of the component. If path is specified, I can use `FileInputStream` to load those properties files from absolute path as follows:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = new 
FileInputStream("C:\\me\\prop\\sample.properties");
prop.load(input);
```

I can read property files present in my project's `src\main\resources\properties` folder as follows:

```
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(properties\sample.properties));
```

These properties gets embedded in my jar at `myjar.jar\properties\sample.properties`

Can I use `FileInputStream` to also read properties from relative path so that I wont have two different approaches in my properties loader class?

Comment: I believe you cannot use relative path with FileInputStream. Though you can try directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative path but it will be relative to the working folder of your java application. Within your IDE (f.e. Eclipse) you can write:

```
new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/properties/sample.properties");
```

because the working folder is the root folder of your project.

It will not found files embedded in your jar.

If you ask for a File object it is possible to point to an external file or an embedded resource:

```
File resource=new File(Ff.class.getResource("/org/json/CDL.class").getFile());
```